# Swift mapView load more pins

Tags: swift, annotations, mkmapview, mapkit

I have a method that showing me multiple Annotations on the map. Its About 10 000 annotation so i have to show only annotation that are visible on the map in current time. When I move with map i execute method that return me objects with coordinates that will be visible. But my method will delete all of them and start to adding them to map one by one. My goal is when I present Annotations and i move with map i want to keep the ones that are visible and the others remove. I am using this and FBAnnotationClusteringSwift framework. 
this is my method for adding pins.

```
private var arrOfPinsOnMap:[FBAnnotation] = []
private var clusteringManager = FBClusteringManager()

func addMapPoints(){

    self.arrOfPinsOnMap.removeAll()
    self.clusteringManager = FBClusteringManager() //everytime recreate instance otherwise there will be duplicates.

                for i in 0..<sortedObjectsByDistance_ids.count {
                    var id_pobor = String()
                    let pin = FBAnnotation()
                    guard let tempUniqueE21 = get_sortedObjectsByDistance(i) else {
                        continue
                    }

                    let temp = tempUniqueE21
                    pin.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: tempUniqueE21.lat, longitude: tempUniqueE21.lng)
                    pin.title = temp.provoz
                    pin.subtitle = temp.ulice

                    self.clusteringManager.addAnnotations([pin])
                    self.arrOfPinsOnMap.append(pin)
            } 
}
```

I am calling this method overtime when user move with map. The problem is not with FB framework but with stored Annotation values.